# Write midi file in JAVA

Tags: java, midi

I try to write simple midi file in java but I'm not able to open it.
I just create three notes played simultanously.

this is my code:

```
    file_midi.write("MThd".getBytes());
    file_midi.write(fourToBytes(length));
    file_midi.write(formatType);
    file_midi.write(nbreVoies);
    file_midi.write(PPQN);

    file_midi.write("MTrk".getBytes());
    file_midi.write(fourToBytes(31));

    temp = (char)choix_inst[0];

    file_midi.write(zero);
    file_midi.write(c);
    file_midi.write(zero);

    num_note_midi = 50;
    velocity = 10;

    file_midi.write(zero);
    file_midi.write(non);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    num_note_midi = 60;

    file_midi.write(zero);
    file_midi.write(non);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    num_note_midi = 70;

    file_midi.write(zero);
    file_midi.write(non);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    num_note_midi = 50;
    t_note_midi = 160;

    file_midi.write(WriteVarLen(t_note_midi));
    file_midi.write(noff);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    num_note_midi = 60;

    file_midi.write(WriteVarLen(t_note_midi));
    file_midi.write(noff);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    num_note_midi = 70;

    file_midi.write(WriteVarLen(t_note_midi));
    file_midi.write(noff);
    file_midi.write(num_note_midi); //numÃ©ro de la note
    file_midi.write(velocity); //vÃ©locitÃ© de la note

    file_midi.write(zero);
    file_midi.write(ff);
    file_midi.write(a_2f);
    file_midi.write(zero);

    file_midi.close();
```

then I get this midi file displayed in hex format, whitch seems to correspond to normal midi file format.

```
4D 54 68 64 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 01 00 A0 4D 54 72 6B 00 00 00 1F 00 C0 00 00 90 32 0A 00 90 3C 0A 00 90 46 0A A0 80 32 0A A0 80 3C 0A A0 80 46 0A 00 FF 2F 00
```

what's wrong with my file ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to open it"? Does it not play in a midi file player?

Comment: it's impossible to play it or even open it with a sheet editor like MuseScore, apparently there's a problem with the end of file, the exact error is unexpected EOF.

Answer (score 0):

That `WriteVarLen` function does not work correctly.

The value 160, encoded as a variable-length quantity, must result in the bytes `81 20`.

Comment: is that a problem with little or big endian ?

Comment: my function is byte[] WriteVarLen(long value)
 {
  byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(value).array();
  
  int size = bytes.length;
  int u,i = 0,size_new_bytes;
  
  while (bytes[i] == 0 && i <(size-1))
     {
      i++;
     }
  
  size_new_bytes = size - i;
     
     byte[] temp = new byte[size_new_bytes];
     
     for (u=0;u<size_new_bytes;u++) 
     {
      temp[u] = bytes[u+i];
     }

     return temp;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [JFugue](http://www.JFugue.org)? If you did, your code would look like this:

```
// Notes 50, 60, and 70, using the default of a quarter duration, on-velocity of 10
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("50a10 60a10 70a10"); 
MidiFileManager.savePatternAsMidi(pattern, new File("filename.mid"));
```

Throw in a try/catch block in case there's a problem writing the file, and you're done.